# Django 2.0 to 2.2 upgrade centos7

Tags: python-3.6, centos7, django-2.2, django-uploads

i tried updating python from 3.4 to 3.6 changed my os from centos 6 to 7 and django from 2.0 to 2.2. i tried running

## python3 manage.py check and it is working fine

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
and then tried to run server and got following exception

```
python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):



File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/saas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/opt/saas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 453, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/opt/saas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/opt/saas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/opt/saas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 206, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "/opt/saas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 123, in load_disk
    app_config.label,
    TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

please help me with this issue